# Does $f(x) = ln(1+2x+2x^2) - 2x$ have a critical point at x = 0?

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion

If we taylor expand $f(x)$ we get: $f(x) = \frac{-4}{3}x^3+O(x^4)$

We also know that $f(0) = 0$.

The correct answer is no, because f(x) will be negative for positive x close to zero, and positive for negative x close to zero. Which makes sense, but since f(0) = 0, we could say that x = 0 is an inflection point, which would make it a critical point. Or is an inflection point not a critical point? Where do I have it wrong?

Comment: What's your definition of critical points?

Comment: @Vim I don't have a definition... This is an example from an exam.

Comment: See conditions of inflection point here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_%28mathematics%29

Comment: @lawls Critical point is when the derivative is equal to 0 or is not defined (but the function is defined), and an inflection point is when a function changes its concavity (up<->down). This would probably clear the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle y = \ln(1+2x+2x^2)-2x\;,$ Then $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2+4x}{1+2x+2x^2}-2 = \frac{-4x^2}{1+2x+2x^2}$

Now for Critical points, $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$ or $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = $ Does not exists.

Comment: So an inflection point is not a critical point?

Comment: @lawls No they're not the same thing.